# WordPress Admin Tag-cloud auto-expand

Tags: jquery, wordpress, tags, admin, tag-cloud

I need to do a custom WordPress edit product page where the 'Most used tags' list is expanded. I tried to add this in `functions.php` inside an `admin_head` function:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    jQuery(".tagcloud-link").attr( "aria-expanded", "true" );
    jQuery( ".the-tagcloud" ).show();
});
```

The code runs but the `.the-tagcloud` element is not visible.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you try to display an element which isn't present in the DOM when you load the page...

The element ".the-tagcloud" is generated when you click on the link for the first time and not till then just displayed or hidden on every further click!

But you can simply trigger the click with jquery, I tested the following code and it worked for me:

```
function load_custom_wp_admin_style() { ?>
<script>
    jQuery(window).load(function() {
        jQuery(".tagcloud-link").trigger("click");
    });
</script>
<?php }
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'load_custom_wp_admin_style' );
```

Comment: The problem was, that I was loading the script in the admin_header section.

Comment: But your code won't work in footer too as explained above the code must be slightly different as mine is...